# Usage of "der/die/das eine" and "der-/die-/dasjenige"

Tags: difference, usage

What is the difference *der/die/das eine* and *der-/die-/dasjenige*? Do they mean 'the one'?

> 1. Er ist ***derjenige***, der aus Berlin kommt.
> 2. Er ist ***der eine***, der aus Berlin kommt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.)** It does indeed mean `the one`. It could be replaced with `der`, but the former is more accurate.

**Example:**

> Er ist **der**, der aus Berlin kommt.
>
> Er ist ***derjenige***, der aus Berlin kommt.
>
> *He is **the one** (who comes) from Berlin.*

**Other examples:**

> Sie ist **die / diejenige**, die ihn begleitet hat.
>
> Außer **denen / denjenigen**, die sonst noch dabei waren.

**2.)** The expression `der eine` from your 2nd is not used.

Comment: Er ist der eine, der aus Berlin kommt, und der da hinten ist der andere, der aus Berlin kommt.

Comment: OK, in rare cases, it might be possibly to use such an expression, however it still has a different meaning then.